Effective spectral gap lemma
I'm trying to understand the effective spectral gap lemma, a tool used in the context of query complexity and quantum walks.
If $\Delta, \Pi$ are two orthogonal projectors and $U = (2\Pi - I)(2\Delta - I)$, then any normalized quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ satisfying $\Delta |\psi\rangle = 0$ is such that
$$\lVert P_{\omega} \Pi |\psi\rangle\rVert \le \omega/2$$
where $P_\omega$ projects onto the eigenspaces of $U$ with eigenvalue $e^{i\theta}$, $|\theta| < \omega$.
Although I can understand the statement and the proof (see, e.g., here), I can't really construct an intuition around it.
It is clear to me that $\Delta |\psi\rangle = 0$ means that $|\psi\rangle$ gets completely reflected by the first part of $U$, and because of that, if $|\psi\rangle$ is associated with a small rotation angle, then it shouldn't change too much, but $(2\Delta - I)$ completely flipped it, so also $(2\Pi - I)$ should (almost) completely flip it as well in order to make it return to the initial state. But this would make sense if the actual statement was $\lVert \Pi |\psi\rangle \rVert \le \omega/2$ for $P_\omega |\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$.
Do you have a better interpretation for it?

Understand it first for the case of 2x2 matrices. Due to Jordan's Lemma, any statement about two orthogonal projectors can be reduced to the case of 2x2 matrices.
